# ORA-6502 while processing a bulky JSON string in PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I am getting ORA-6502 while processing a bulky JSON string in PL/SQL.

My Code to process the JSON String is as follows:

```
declare
  json_lst  json_list;
  bulk_rec  CLOB; -- Variable to hold JSON String
begin
   json_lst := json_list (bulk_rec);
   json_obj_mast_lst := json_list (json_obj.get ('ABC')); 

   /* Above line give the Error that reads
      ORA-06502 : PL/SQL : numeric or value error : character string buffer too 
      small

      and this error leads me to package "JSON_PRINTER" where the following line raises the error
        when 'string' then
           if(mem.num = 1) then
             buf := buf || llcheck('"'||escapeString(mem.get_string)||'"'); --Error
           else
             buf := buf || llcheck('/**/'||mem.get_string||'/**/');
           end if;
   */
end;
```

Comment: How long is your bulky JSON string?

Comment: Looks like a known issue.... see https://github.com/oberstet/pljson/issues/3 for a description of the issue.

Comment: It has 57751 characters

Comment: I found the solution to the above , Just replaced the 

json_obj_mast_lst := json_list (json_obj.get ('ABC')); 

with  

dbms_lob.createtemporary(json_obj_mast_lst,TRUE);
json_value.TO_CLOB (json_lst.get (i), json_obj_mast_lst);